# Port Mappings from environment variables in AWS ECS Task Definition

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ecs, ecs-taskdefinition

Is there a way to specify container port from environment variable in AWS ECS Task Definition?

This is in my task-definition.json which is used by Github Actions

```
"containerDefinitions": [
    {
        "portMappings": [
            {
                "containerPort": 3037  <=== Can this come from environment variable defined below?
            }
        ],
        "essential": true,
        "environment": [
            {
                "name": "PORT",
                "value": "3037"
            }
        ]
    }
],
"requiresCompatibilities": ["EC2"]
```

Comment: Where? In CloudFormation or terraform?

Comment: @Marcin No, I am not using CloudFormation or terraform
I am using Basic ECS-task-definition.json

Comment: I see. No, you can't do this. You have to create new version of your task definition with a new port.

Comment: It's a flat JSON file, it has no concept of a process with environment variables.